# could django update foreignkey use SQL?

Tags: django, postgresql

I filled datas into postgreSQL without type foreignkey at first.

here is my models.py

```
class BeverageMenu(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)                 
    area = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)      

class DMenu(models.Model):
    dmenu = models.ForeignKey(BeverageMenu,null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

and I use this way to update the foreignkey:

```
>>> from psql.models import BeverageMenu,DMenu
>>> menu1 = BeverageMenu.objects.get(id=1)    
>>>product = DMenu.objects.filter(area='North')
>>>product.update(dmenu=menu1)
```

And I want to know could I use SQL directly to do this ?

I try this but fail

```
INSERT INTO psql_dmenu(category,product,dmenu) VALUES ('hot','soup',1), 

ERROR:  column "dmenu" of relation "psql_dmenu" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but why would you want to? Django has a model layer for a reason, which is to make the database easier to deal with and less dependent on SQL.

However, for your problem, the issue is that the underlying database column for a ForeignKey includes the prefix _id: so your field is `dmenu_id`.